# How to make the text written in a text box tilt to the right?

Tags: html, css

I would like to make the written text in a text box tilt to its right.
Can anybody help me with the code for that? Perhaps some kind of a font-family?

Comment: Use [CSS 2D Transforms](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp).

Comment: http://www.css3maker.com/text-rotation.html

Comment: Are you asking how to make text *italic*?

Comment: That could work, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean?

```
<input type="text" style="text-align:right; direction:rtl" />
```

> Update:1

[text rotation](http://www.css3maker.com/text-rotation.html)

use this tool to make rotation and get css code.

> Update 2:

You can use this

```
<p contenteditable="true">This is an editable paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: Not really. I would like to keep my text in the center but to use, I don't know, maybe some kind of a font family to make it tilt to the right, so it'll look better. Rotation moves the whole text box when being applied.

Comment: Yes, but this rotation moves my whole text box, and I only want to rotate the text written in it. How can I apply it only on the text written?

Comment: @user3804691 Just add the css on the text instead of the div it's in?

Comment: @ Déjà vu idea or see update and use it.